# jquery method not invoked for second time

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what I have in my code. It is invoked only once. I need to refresh the page to call this function again.

```
$('#btnajaxcontrol').click(function () {
var mail = document.getElementById("txtmail").value;
var fname = document.getElementById("txtfname").value;
var lname = document.getElementById("txtlname").value;
var addr = document.getElementById("txtaddress").value;
var mobile = document.getElementById("txtmobile").value;
if (ValidateEmail(mail) && !(mail == "") && !(fname == "") && !(lname == "") && !(addr == "") && !(mobile == "")) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "CRUDwebserviceJS.asmx/registerWS",
        data: { 'email': mail, 'firstname': fname, 'lastname': lname, 'address': addr, 'mobile': mobile },
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var wsres = data.d;
            if (wsres == 'true') {
                $('#lblmsg').html('User Successfully Registered...');
            }
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert(result);
            $('#lblmsg').html('User Registeration faild...!');
            $("#lblmsg").css('background', 'red');
        }
    });
}
});
```

Comment: please, add a jsfiddle (or at least the html concerned).

Comment: Does this code placed with AJAX?AJAX might break the event binding.

Comment: Also, if you are using `jQuery`, why dont you use `$("#txtmail").val()`?

Comment: Most likely because there is an error in either the client or server side somewhere. Could you share a jsfiddle as @Shitsu suggested?

Comment: Might not be an error, because it works for first time not second time, as he said. And this might happen if AJAX comes in to picture

Comment: You can try `$(document).on("click","#btnajaxcontrol",function () {`

Comment: `!(mail == "")` can be written as `mail != ""`

Comment: Do you have error(s) in your console? Are you sure your code does not enter the function? Have you checked it with a debugger? Are you sure the button exists when you want to click on it for the second time?